# Why is MSE used in yolo

Tags: conv-neural-network, yolo, loss

The questions might be weird but why is MSE used in yolo, I mean to say that x,w,h,w is always less than the dimensions of the image . So we can simply rescale them and use binary crossentropy . I might be making a mistake,I know but can you explain this to me.